# SOLR high CPU utilization in amazon linux

Tags: solr, amazon-ec2, cpu

I installed solr-3.6 in my **local windows box** and it worked fine.

I installed solr-4.0 in amazon ec2 **linux large instance** and the cpu usage shot upto 100%. It maintained at 80-90% average cpu power.

I thought it could be because of 4.0, So I installed 3.6 in EC2 again. But again the CPU usage was 80-90% average.

With both the versions, solr works in EC2. dont know why CPU usage is so high.

In my local box java 1.7 is installed and in EC2 it is 1.6.0_24.
I have mapped solr dir to an EBS volume.

```
/dev/mapper/vg1-solr   8361916   1935928   6342128  24% /home/ec2-user/SOLR/solr/example/solr
```

Is there any known issue ?

Comment: PLEASE MENTION WHY THIS IS BEING DOWNVOTED ? WHAT MAKES YOU THINK THAT THIS NOT A RELEVANT QUESTION ?

Comment: Not that is not relevant, I guess people are downvoting it because it is not about software development (off-topic). It probably should be on [SuperUser](http://superuser.com) or [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com).

Comment: dont understand why such separation :-(

Comment: The public is a bit different... if you read the FAQ (last option on the top menu) of each site you'll notice the scope varies a bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We faced just this issue yesterday - the problem is because of the leap second on June 30 2012. A linux kernel component that manages sleep times isn't updated to the correct time and this causes extremely high CPU usage for Java processes. [Related question on serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/403732/anyone-else-experiencing-high-rates-of-linux-server-crashes-during-a-leap-second) and my fix I derived from it (for Debian):

(issue these commands from the command line)

```
export LANG="en_EN"
date -s "`date`"

/etc/init.d/ntp stop
ntpdate pool.ntp.org
/etc/init.d/ntp start
```

For Red Hat derived systems, I believe you replace `ntp` with `ntpd`.